# Java - Where is the reference of a member variable stored in memory?

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I have a question about JVM memory and hope to get help and guidance from everyone.

---

```
Class A {
   //memory variable
   int i = 2;
   Integer j = new Integer(3);

   public void static main(){
       //local variable
       int a = 2;
       Integer b = new Integer(3);
   } 
}
```

In the code above, I want to know if the reference to the member variable is stored in the heap or the stack.

### What I think I know

- `i` is a member variable and a primitive variable.
- `j` is a member variable and a reference variable.
- `a`  is a local variable and a primitive variable.
- `b` is a local variable and a reference variable.

### And my conclusion :

member variables

1. `i` and it's value is stored in the heap
2. `j` and the object it refers to (`new Integer(3)`) is stored in the heap

local variables

3. `a` and it's value is stored in stack.
4. `b` stored in the stack, but the object it refers to (`new Integer(3)`) is stored in the heap.

---

Is my conclusion correct?
My biggest confusion is on the second point. Is `j` stored in heap?
Please help me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/65289/54997

Comment: Your conclusion is correct.

Comment: Since you are not creating any instance of `A`, no value is ever stored for `i` and `j`.

Comment: ok,I already know.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct.

More specifically, `j` is in the heap because it's part of an object of type `A`, and objects are in the heap.